# How to move cursor to next or previous character when focus is on cells in Editable Grid (View)

Tags: dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven, editablegrid

Current default behavior in Editable Grids (Views): when the focus is on the cells the Right arrow (→) key moves the cursor to the next field, when the focus is on the cells the Left arrow (→) key moves the cursor to the previous field.

Looking for keyboard shortcuts to move the cursor the a next/previous character in stead of a next field/previous field.

Your support is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here -Keyboard Shortcuts Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav-app/keyboard-shortcuts-windows-client

Right Arrow:    Move to the next field or character

Left Arrow: Move to the previous field or character

Comment: Thank you Sara. I actually need the shortcuts for the Unified Interface used in Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement (Sales, Field Services) and Power Apps - Model Driven...